# A word for "taking some foods from pot and putting it in to the plate"

Tags: vocabulary

What word should you use to ask someone to "take foods from the pot and put it into the plate"?

You may say stuff like "take some food" but it does not exactly mean the act of "taking food from the pot and putting it into the plate". Is there a word for that in English?

Comment: I think you're talking about *serving* or *doling* food! but I'm not sure. You might want to visit [ell.se]; they might be more helpful with this kind of question.

Comment: @BraddSzonye "serving" is what I was looking for. Does _doling_ used for food?

Comment: Yes, *doling* is used for food.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say "serve" or "dish out".

"She served the food equally among the four plates".

"She dished out more curry for herself than the others."

There's no word in English which would be specific to pots and plates, however, so if that's important information you'd have to still say it:

"Instead of using bowls, he dished the sauce onto the plates, to everyone's surprise".

If it's soup, you use a ladle: "He ladled the soup into each ones' bowl".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!